# Is it "deep-sky object" or "deep sky object"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

What is correct, *deep-sky object* or *deep sky object*? Does common usage trump grammar?

Or, alternatively, if they are both correct, which one should be preferred?

*[Inconclusive discussion on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Deep_sky_object#To_hyphenate_or_not_to_hyphenate...)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling around, I find that the non-hyphenated form is considerably more prevalent.
But as for grammar, the hyphenated form is more correct, since *deep* is modifying *sky*, not *object*.

> Deep-sky object = [Deep sky] [object]

The non-hyphenated form would be correct if both *deep* and *sky* were modifying *object*:

> Deep sky object = [Deep] [sky object] *or* [Sky object which is also deep]

The best clincher on this I could come up with is that [Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=deep%20-%20sky%20object,deep%20sky%20object&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which only analyzes books, has no instances of *deep sky object*; only of *deep-sky object*:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=deep+-+sky+object%2Cdeep+sky+object&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Granted, there are not many hits, but it's still a lot compared with zero.

If I had to choose, I would choose the hyphenated form.

Comment: I like statistical evidence as much as the next guy, but the Ngram just demonstrates that editors employed by printing houses have a good grasp of grammar. mental note: Gotta learn to use 'ngrams'

Answer (score 0):

The inconclusive discussion is a Wikipedia article about a game by that name where the article was apparently *highjacked* by astronomers - what would *they* know?

Both spellings are used in the article. But there doesn't seem to be confusion.

The answer to your question might depend on who you're communicating with: astronomers or grammarians.

But I suspect both parties would say "*It doesn't matter*"

Comment: It's true that there is little confusion, but there is a right answer as far as English goes.

Comment: It's appalling to admit it *here*, but my sympathies go with the *astronomers*.