# Shorebased, Shore-based or Shore Based?

Tags: punctuation, orthography, hyphenation

What is the best or correct way to spell this adjective (e.g. shorebased training)?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/10041

Answer (score 4):

According to [Google Ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=shorebased%2Cshore+based%2Cshore+-+based&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *shore-based* is the most common (and in this case the best) form of this phrase:

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=shorebased%2Cshore+based%2Cshore+-+based&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3