# "n-degenerate" or "n degenerate"?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

In physics, we say that something is "degenerate" when it exists in more than one "equivalent" versions. What is the proper form of saying that there are *n* versions of X -- that X is "n-degenerate" or "n degenerate"? I have used the first form in my paper, but the editor changed it to the second. It is possible that they were wrong, hence my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*N-degenerate* is correct here, since the hyphen shows that *n* modifies *degenerate*, and not *X*.  So *[n-degenerate] X* is the meaning, not *n [degenerate Xs]*.

Take *American-football player*, for another example.  Without the hyphen, the player is American, not the football.  A general rule of thumb is that when a word modifies an adjective, it is proper to hyphenate.

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word/34766#34766) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) are a great follow-up from here.