# Preposition following "estimated"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions

I'm working on a scientific paper and I want to convey the idea that I have obtained some data by using a certain source. The phrase I wrote was:

> The turbulent fluxes at the air-sea interface are estimated by using in-situ data from a moored buoy of the Prediction and Research Moored Array over the Tropical Atlantic Ocean.

Is the *by* in the phrase correctly used?

Comment: Is *in situ* really spelled with a hyphen?

Comment: Not when it's a noun.  But when it's an adjective, it [wants a hyphen.](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/10041)  Many people use it as an adjective without the hyphen, though, so it wouldn't be wrong if it was changed.

Comment: I'm using in situ to describe the 'quality' of the data, that it was measured, well, in situ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of "by using" is often encountered in scientific articles and literature. I suppose your example is from a similar source.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the usage of *[by](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/by)* in your sentence is correct, though unnecessary.  You could remove the *by* and retain the original meaning:

> The turbulent fluxes at the air-sea interface are estimated using in-situ data ...