# "You should be well-organised" or "You should be well organised"?

Tags: hyphenation

Should I hyphenate the term 'well organised'? The context, if it matters, is the following sentence:

> For this role you should be well organised and analytical with some research ability.

(I see there are other question here about hyphenation; do point me to one if this falls under a general rule, I just couldn't see it.)

Comment: related: [How does the hyphen change the meaning in expressions like “high performance” and “high-performance”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45945/how-does-the-hyphen-change-the-meaning-in-expressions-like-high-performance-an)

Comment: possible duplicate of [To hyphenate or not?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11570/to-hyphenate-or-not)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course the context matters. I think it tells you whether a hyphen is needed or not.

Use a hyphen with compound adjectives (such as *well-organized*) when they precede a noun.

- It was a well-organized meeting.

When the description follows the noun, no hyphen is necessary.

- Her office is well organized.

In your example, I would not hyphenate the phrase.

Comment: Is "well-organized" a compound adjective if "well" is an adverb?

Comment: A compound adjective can have an adverb. See this link: http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/hyphen

Comment: Another way to think of it is that as a prefix adjective, it’s hyphenated, but as a complement, it isn’t. If that’s too complicated, just say to hyphenate it if comes before the noun it applies to, but not to do so if it comes afterwards. That’s a bit loose, I know. *I’m looking for a well-organized and well-disciplined candidate.*; *I’m looking for a candidate [who is] both well organized and well disciplined.*

Answer (score 4):

My impression is that, although most people prefer not to use a hyphen here, it is not necessarily completely unacceptable to hyphenate "well-organized" in this context.

A hyphen could be supported by analogy with phrases like "well-known", which dictionaries such as [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-known) indicate may be used with a hyphen even in predicative position:

> If someone **is well-known** for a particular activity, a lot of people know about them because of their involvement with that activity.
>
> [...]
>
> - He **is well-known** to the local police.
> - Hubbard **was well-known** for his work in the field of drug rehabilitation.
>
> [...]
>
> - It **is well-known** that bamboo shoots are a panda's staple diet.
>
> [...]
>
> Something or someone that **is well-known** is famous or familiar.

That said, Collins in fact indicates that the spelling "[well organized](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/well-organized)" is or should be used in this context:

> **well organized** when postpositive

So the issue of how to hyphenate adjective phrases of this type in this context is a little unclear. (Hyphenation is one of the less consistent areas of English orthography.)

I wrote an answer to a related question, *[Hyphen: “well defined” vs. “well-defined”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410283/hyphen-well-defined-vs-well-defined),* that I think is relevant. Here is a portion of it (slightly modified):

---

As described in Sven Yargs's answer to the following question ([Should there be a hyphen in expressions such as “currently-available X”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/367316/should-there-be-a-hyphen-in-expressions-such-as-currently-available-x/367336#367336)), hyphens are generally only avoided **after the adverb *very,* or after any adverb ending in *-ly.*** There is no generally observed rule that I am aware of forbidding the use of a hyphen after other kinds of adverbs, such as *well, quick, hard.*

There are many phrases starting with "well" that are commonly hyphenated, mostly ending in participles or departicipial adjectives, like *well-read* and *well-known.*  (Examples starting with other adverbs: *quick-thinking* and *hard-working*).

The hyphenation of adjective phrases in predicative position seems to be a bit more variable than that of adjective phrases in attributive position, but using a hyphen in this kind of context is considered correct by at least some stylebooks:

> These sentences are both correct:
>
> - He is well known for his philanthropy. (*Well known* describes *he.*)
> - His well-known philanthropy is the subject of a new book. (*Well-known* describes *philanthropy.*)
>
> Supporting the distinction above are *Garner's Modern American Usage, The Chicago Manual of Style,* and *The Gregg Reference Manual.*
>
> [...]
>
> But ***well-known* is also acceptable in both sentences** according to *The Associated Press Stylebook* (AP). The rule in AP is that "when a modifier that would be hyphenated before a noun occurs instead after a form of the verb *to be,* the hyphen usually must be retained to avoid confusion." AP gives this example: "The man is well-known."
>
> So, I hope the answer is now well known to you: Both *well-known* and *well known* are correct. You choose.

–"[A Well-Known Problem: Well Known](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2009/07/a-wellknown-problem-well-known-.html)", by  Lynn Gaertner-Johnston, *Business Writing Blog*

---

The Corpus of Contemporary American English has 21 results (excluding spoken examples) for "is well organized" (8 from magazine articles, 5 from newspaper articles, and 8 from academic texts) vs. only 6 for "is well-organized" (4 from newspaper articles and 2 from academic texts).

I excluded spoken language examples because I assume their classification just represents the choice of the transcriber, but there were 3 for "is well organized" and 2 for "is well-organized".

Answer (score -2):

No, in this case it should not be hyphenated.

As a general guide, you should hyphenate such things when they are functioning as an adjective - "he was a well-organised man".

Comment: In OP's example, "well organized" can be interpreted as an adjective. You can easily replace it with another adjective, so it passes the test.

Comment: Dropping in another adjective is not a test as we are discussing a compound construction. To *function* as an adjective, a compound needs a following noun to modify. This is why, as JLG correctly informs us (at the same minute that I was posting...) a compound is hyphenated as a pre-modifier to a noun, but not as a post-modifier when it is no longer adjectival. In the OP's example there is no following noun.

Comment: So in 'He was cold', are you saying that 'cold' doesn't function as an adjective?

Comment: Of course it is, but have you noticed that 'cold' is not a compound? In 'he is a well organised man' the attribute is 'organised' and the 'well' is just flapping around; not really part of the noun phrase. To make the whole thing an attribute - to function as a single adjective - they need to be linked with a hyphen. This is not a complicated idea...  When it is predicative the issue doesn't arise as we are no longer trying to force 'well' and 'organised' to act in unison as a single adjective.