# If "often" is used as an adverb, does it need to be hyphenated?

Tags: american-english

In this sentence, should "often difficult" be hyphenated?

> At the arcade the brothers were able to leave behind their often difficult domestic situation.

My gut instinct tells me it should be hyphenated, but "often-difficult" looks odd to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Should I used a dash for “often-used” and “well-documented”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225433/should-i-used-a-dash-for-often-used-and-well-documented).

Comment: Yes, it should be hyphenated. If you could post some research, that would prolly resolve your difficulty without further ado.

Answer (score 1):

A hyphen is rarely used with the word *often*, but is commonly used with its archaic form *oft*.

> No doubt they are subsequently guided to higher excellence and effectiveness with the experience gained in their **oft-repeated** performance.

> It was in reference to this speech that he made the **oft-quoted** remark that he "would rather be right than be president."

It is common for *oft-* to be followed by a past participle, as in the previous examples. More rarely, it is followed by an adjective, as in this example:

> The Phoenix Suns got a chance to inhale on Tuesday night, as this year’s **oft-anticlimactic** but ever-consequential draft lottery went down in Chicago for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your gut may have a leg up on your eyes here. But anatomical-idiomatic punnery aside...

The latest issue of the Chicago Manual of Style (16) has a wonderful, multipage chart on hyphenation (§7.85) that I refer to often for answers to puzzles like this one. For **adverb not ending in** ***ly*** **+ participle or adjective** it gives a *Summary of [this] rule*:

> *"Hypenated before but not after a noun; compounds with* more, most, less, least, *and* very *usually left open unless ambiguity threatens. When the adverb rather than the compound as a whole is modified by another adverb, the entire expression is open.*

The "usually" in *...usually left open...* seems to suggest there is some measure of pull away from hyphenation of commonly-compounded adverbials (see what I did there?) among which you might include "often-" (though not named here in Chicago).

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) shows this *Often* compound hyphenated before a noun (with a liberal parameter space of +6) roughly **8 times more frequently** than not (~3500:450).

In short, your eyes could probably get away with taking the win, but some readers' guts might look twice.

Comment: +1 just for all the laughs