# Should one hyphenate 'shoulder width' in this context?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation, parts-of-speech

I believe that in this context:

> Place your feet shoulder-width apart.

it makes sense to hyphenate to avoid confusion.  I see that `apart` is listed as an adverb in the dictionary and `width` as a noun, so it would appear `shoulder` is an adjective of the noun `width` in this context.

I see this as possibly matching one [published rule for hyphenating](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp):

> Rule 2b. When writing out new, original, or unusual compound nouns, writers should hyphenate whenever doing so avoids confusion.

Is that correct?  However, I feel in this example:

> Place your feet apart by a shoulder width.

it should not be hyphenated.  Is this correct?  What are the rules that apply in these two cases?  Are they really the same case?

---

I do not believe this is a duplicate of [the suggested question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45945/how-does-the-hyphen-change-the-meaning-in-expressions-like-high-performance-an) since I'm asking about the parts of speech of the possibly hyphenated words and which if any of the hyphenation rules applies to this situation, such as the mentioned compound noun rule.

Comment: I think this is probably a dup of [How does the hyphen change the meaning in expressions like “high performance” and “high-performance”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45945/how-does-the-hyphen-change-the-meaning-in-expressions-like-high-performance-an)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've noted why I don't feel this is a dup in the question.

Comment: I believe the first should be "Place your feet *a* shoulder width apart."

Comment: @Hotlicks that would be unusual in UK usage, especially as the implication is "*your own* shoulder width".

Comment: @ChrisH - Then, if you place your feet two shoulder widths apart, whose shoulders do you use for the second?

Comment: @HotLicks that's not commonly used, "wide apart" would be used instead.  It's a description rather than a unit of measure.

Comment: In this case I would write it the way it is spoken--in one quick breath, i.e., shoulderwidth,  Some compound words aren't worth hyphenating. Commercialese slips into the written language, e.g.,'Footlong Subway'--a sandwich of a certain length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Place your feet apart by a shoulder width" means to literally place your feet apart by the width of one shoulder.  This does not seem to be the intention, and as such it is incorrect.

When you hyphenate, you combine the terms into a new adjective with a new, possibly idiomatic meaning, that is the width from the left shoulder to the right shoulder in a person.

It should also be noted 'shoulders-width' is also a common usage of this term.