# What would be the proper writing of head-end, as a single word or two words separated by comma or space?

Tags: orthography

I see 3 ways of writing [headend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_television_headend):

- `headend`
- `head end`
- `head-end`

Note, I already know that all of them are acceptable but it has to be one that would be better.

To make the problem more interesting, if I would apply [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) convention to it, it should be `Headend` or `HeadEnd`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? All three variants occur, but most people won't even know what the "word" means. It's somewhat specialised vocabulary, so I suggest in most cases where you might use it, you're interacting with others who are also using it. Copy the form they use.

Comment: @Sorin: You will need to say what you mean by "it has to be one that would be better".  Do you mean which of the three is best? (How-to-camelcase is a separate question, I think, than that.)  If so, best for what?  BTW, edit the question to fix its problems, rather than explaining in a comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen all three variations, though **head-end** looks the clearest and unambiguous to me.

For CamelCase, there is no official definition, but I'd go with **headEnd**.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing quite what you mean by "better," I'd go with the conventions that an industry leader like Cisco observes in [this document](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CHkQFjAG&url=http://www.cisco.com/en/US/solutions/collateral/ns341/ns524/ns610/net_brochure0900aecd80613e44.pdf&ei=AK7nToeuBMv-sQKp1vmUCQ&usg=AFQjCNFhIa8-1UWLDw0FctH6-wAlokDkIw&sig2=k-m7K6yORpbUjCdYT70azg):

- *headend*, in one conjoined word
- *Headend*, with no camel cap in the middle

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using this in the context of the head end of a list or something similar, as opposed to the tail end.

"Headend" is not a word.  "Head" is here an adjective and "end" is the noun, so "head-end" would be the adjective form, e.g. "The head-end object is..."  The noun, which it sounds like you're looking for, is just plain "head end," e.g. "The head end of the list..."  Therefore, the camel-case capitalization, if you *must* use it, would be "headEnd."