# "How-to" or "how to" in reference to tutorial

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Should I refer to a tutorial as a *how-to* or a *how to*? Is there a grammatical rule for this?

Comment: When you're wondering whether something is a word, your first stop should be a dictionary. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/how-to shows that the hyphenated form can be used as both a noun and an adjective.

Comment: A previous [hyphen question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word) has good answers and includes links to hyphenating how-to's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***How-to***

That is how it is to be written, as you mean a certain thing (the way) defined by the phrase. Without a hyphen it would not refer to the specific thing but just be a phrase.

Between

> "The how-to of it all is explained in this tutorial."

and

> "This tutorial shows how to do it all."

There is a distinct difference.

Comment: Another comparison sentence would be something like "The steps for building this model are explained in the how-to available on our website" - i.e. using *how-to* as a noun rather than an adjective.

Comment: What if you use it as an adjective like "click here to watch my _how-to_ video"? You still use the hyphen, right?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath Correct.