# Correct hyphenation of "ever-more-connected"

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

What would be the correct way to hyphenate the phrase "ever-more-connected"? Does it even need hyphens?

An example sentence:

> They were excited about the new possibilities in their ever-more-connected world.

My instinct is to hyphenate it as I have here, but I'm not 100% sure and searching the internet turned up no specific explanations.

Comment: Nick, welcome to English.SE.  Your question has been asked before so this question will probably be closed as a duplicate.  There's no shame in that, and I hope you'll stick around and continue to ask questions.

Comment: Yes, specifically the advice to "use hyphenation ... to join a word to a past participle to create a single adjective preceding the noun it modifies"