# How do I spell "subdistrict"?

Tags: american-english, orthography

Geographically, there are voting districts, taxing districts, and school districts. There are also subdistricts. I have found different spellings of this word (*subdistrict*, *sub district*, *sub-district*). Which one is correct for the USA?

Comment: I feel a dictionary would be a more efficient way to answer this. [Sub-district](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sub-district)

Comment: Actually, Dictionary.com's definition is under the entry *[subdistrict](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subdistrict)*.  It eliminated your hyphen to find the entry you linked.

Comment: @Danielδ - I must have misspelled it the first time - it asked me if I meant sub-district.

Comment: @Matt What asked you?

Comment: @Danielδ Dictionary.com

Comment: Funny, Dictionary.com never asked me anything.

Comment: I was going to vote to close as General Reference, but neither the NOAD, nor the OALD or the ODE list any of it.

Comment: Voting to reopen.  Dictionaries do not agree, and some don't even have the word.  British English and American English appear to differ, to which COCA and BNC and some dictionaries bear witness.  Common usage certainly differs, to the point at which @MattЭллен was closing the question since *sub-district* was obviously correct, and tchrist was downvoting the answer because *subdistrict* was obviously correct.

Comment: I agree with you @Danielδ

Answer (score 5):

Since *[sub](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sub-)* is a [prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix), it must be connected to the word, at least by a hyphen.  So *sub district* is out.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subdistrict,sub%20district,sub%20-%20district&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) depicts a pretty consistent fight between the two other forms:

[image]

[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) tells us that in its American literature corpus there are 24 instances of *subdistrict* versus 18 of *sub-district*.  [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) (the British corpus) has no matches for *subdistrict*, but 9 for *sub-district*.  [Dictionary.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subdistrict) and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subdistrict) have their entries without a hyphen (*subdistrict*).  The [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/spellcheck/?q=subdistrict), significantly, does not have an entry for *subdistrict*.

In this case, neither is incorrect in America, though *subdistrict* appears to be slightly preferred. As tchrist comments below, a good American rule of thumb is that productive prefixes such as un-, non-, sub-, etc, should not take hyphens.  However, in British English, *subdistrict* appears to be rare (if not incorrect).  For further information on hyphenating, see [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/10041):

> For the most part, compound words that are created by adding a prefix are not hyphenated.

<sup>Disclaimer regarding Ngram chart: see [this meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2469/10041) for important info on this internet resource.</sup>

Comment: This is yet another case where Ngrams is useless. You have to check with your publisher. For example, [O’Reilly](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html) is quite vehement that the *sub-* prefix not take a hyphen unless prefixing a proper noun. Similarly with *non-*, *multi-*, and *pseudo-*. None of those should be taking a written hyphen. **The general rule of thumb is that *productive prefixes*  should *not* take hyphens.**

Comment: @tchrist I disagree that Ngrams is useless, but your point that it varies from publisher to publisher is a good one.  If you're writing for a certain purpose, check with your publisher/mentor/boss before deciding on a spelling.  Dictionaries, Ngrams, and other corpus analyzers come second.

Comment: @tchrist Also, in spite of your downvote, I cannot concede that *sub-district* is incorrect, since it is the preferred spelling in British English.  Perhaps you should say *American rule of thumb*.

Comment: I’m annoyed at people thinking that Ngrams “proves” anything meaningful. You can’t crowdsource style.

Comment: I am not drawing on the Ngram as a proof.  I've included other sources, and even then I have not called my answer a proof.  I've even included a disclaimer for the Ngram.

Comment: @tchrist I've recanted the "rule of thumb", but in order to include British spellings, I haven't included yours.  As far as I know, your rule holds for American spelling.

Comment: Remembering that the OP specifically asked about the "USA", I decided to include your rule of thumb after all.  We'll see what comes of it.

Comment: @tchrist: *You can’t crowdsource style*? - of course you can! In the final analysis, any usage adopted by the majority for long enough *de facto* eventually becomes "correct". I suspect what you actually mean is that during a transition phase, something you might define as "good style" (for historical or other reasons) could actually be a minority usage. But in the fullness of time, later generations will probably just call it obsolete/archaic.

Comment: @tchrist: I don't really see different usages by competent native speakers as "right/wrong". I don't like it when "Indian English" speakers say things like *"I have a doubt in this concept"*, but I honestly doubt if many/any people who would say that are "native English speakers" by my definition. Nevertheless, as you know perfectly well, English is not a single unified language across the globe - so irritating as it may be to me, I have to acknowledge the "validity" of many Americanisms. (having said that, I happily endorse *"dialog"*, for example! :)

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question and for entertaining me with your arguments! I am surprised by your quick responses and will recommend this site to my colleagues.