# "Publicly well known X" vs "public well known X"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

How do you say it correctly?

> The publicly well-known project

or

> The public well-known project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you’re trying to say. If you want to refer to a public project that’s well known, you need ‘the well-known public project’. If, on the other hand, the project in question is not necessarily a public one, but one which is nevertheless well known to the public, then it would be grammatical to say ‘the publicly well-known project’. Grammatical, but not very likely. What you’d be more likely to hear would be ‘the project well known to the public’.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the first, the adverb *publicly* modifies the adjective (*well-known*), not the noun.  This is grammatically correct.

In the second, the adjective *public* modifies the noun (*project*), not the adjective.  More common in this case would be to switch the adjectives (*The well-known public project*).

Due to the specific words chosen in this case, the meanings are almost the same.  The difference becomes more apparent when you replace *well-known* with *disapproved*:

> The disapproved public project - A project which is open to/created for the public, but disapproved, at least by someone.
>
> The publicly disapproved project - A project which is not necessarily known, but whose disapproval was publicly made.

P.S. I've added hyphens to your *well known*s; it's [the correct way to do it](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34766/10041).