# "England-born" or "English-born"

Tags: word-usage

Which of the two statements is correct?

> He was an **English-born** businessman.
>
> He was an **England-born** businessman.

The same confusion arises in *India-born* and *Indian-born* as well. Moreover, is a hyphen necessary in these examples?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"England-born" is perfectly understandable, but I don't think a native English speaker would say it. "English-born" is a conventional expression.

The question about hyphens has no single answer: it depends whose style guide you are following.

Comment: Thanks @Colin. Reg. the style-guide, is there any other question on this forum that talks about that?

Comment: [This question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word) discusses that and provides [a link](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) to what I consider to be some good advice in that regard.

Comment: @Shyam: In this specific case I think it would be an unusual style guide that suggested writing *"English born"* as two separate words. It's nearly always hyphenated. Sometimes just written as a single word with no hyphen - but that's even less common than the two-word form.

Answer (score 0):

They mean two different things. "English-born" means born with English nationality. "England-born" means born in England. Neither implies the other.

And "England-born" would probably be more commonly phrased "Born in England".