# Life cycle, life-cycle or lifecycle?

Tags: compounds

I notice great variability in how this concept is expressed.  Does the term vary depending on the context?  Should one use one variation when discussing biology, for example, and another when talking about product phases?  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_cycle) uses different forms in way that seems random.  So, too, does the New York Times, based on basic search.  [An earlier discussion](http://www.techwr-l.com/archives/0604/techwhirl-0604-00604.html#.T7a7l3K852g) of the variations in connection with technology notes that "A compound generally starts open (life cycle), migrates to hyphenated (life-cycle), and ends up closed (lifecycle)."  Are we at the closed stage for the term in a general sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

Comment: I don't believe this duplicates the cited question, as it centers on use of hyphens with prefixes.  One of the answers, however does hit the nail on the head: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/893/20519.  It provides sources that say there is no firm rule here--open/closed is driven by convention.  As the diagram below shows, "life cycle" seems to be the most popular usage.

Comment: In software development circles it seems we're already at the closed form, making existing spell-checkers frustrating to use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management

Comment: The Wikipedia entry for [Application_lifecycle_management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_lifecycle_management) links to the [Software_Development_Life_Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Development_Life_Cycle) so while I prefer the form "lifecycle" and believe use is trending that way generally (and especially in our industry of early-adopters) it is still often about context and audience.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My medical dictionaries (*Dorland's Illustrated*, 30th Ed.; *Saunders Comprehensive Veterinary Dictionary*) either list it as two words (Dorland's) or not at all (Saunders). So I would say in medical literature fields, where the context would be something like the life cycle of a parasite, it's still two words.

And I'm not sure that *lifecycle* and *life-cycle* are nearly as common as *life cycle*. Here's the NGram for [life cycle vs. lifecycle vs. life-cycle.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life+cycle%2C+lifecycle%2C+life-cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image]

Comment: The [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life+cycle%2Clifecycle%2Clife-cycle%2Clife+-+cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for *life cycle,lifecycle,life-cycle,life - cycle* is more informative, showing that *life-cycle* is used much more than *lifecycle*.

Comment: @jwpat7, what would adding the space around the hyphen indicate? I'm  not understanding the point. What results would that "catch"?

Comment: My understanding is that in ngrams search string *life-cycle* does not match anything, while search string *life - cycle* matches the string *life-cycle*.

Comment: I’m thinking that your ngram may be wrong; [please consider this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life+cycle%2Clifecycle%2Clife+%22-%22+cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: @tchrist, It may be, but when I look at your link it says "Note: the Ngram Viewer treats quotation marks literally." How do you know that you're searching for *life-cycle* with *life "-" cycle*? Is that how you're supposed to search for hyphenated words?

Comment: @JLG That is is my suspicion, yes. Notice how it doesn’t flat-line now.

Comment: @tchrist, I don't think that's right. When you search for just [*life "-" cycle*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=life+%22-%22+cycle&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=), and you look at what's found, it's not hyphenated life-cycle. It's the separate words life and cycle that are found. Look at the works it find its in below the graph.

Comment: +1 Fact-based answer of incredible quality.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Four online dictionaries I consulted (Merriam-Webster, Oxford Dictionaries, Macmillan, and Dictionary.com) all agree on the open form *[life cycle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/life+cycle?s=t)*.

In particular, the Dictionary.com definition in the link uses the open form for all the senses *life cycle*.

Comment: Language rules change depending on real usage. In Google Search you get 60M of usages for "lifecycle", 102M for "life-cycle" and 113M for "life cycle".

Answer (score 1):

My feeling is that if referring to a single concept, it should be a single or closed word, i.e. *lifecycle*.

On the other hand, when referring to separate concepts, the open usage would be more appropriate. For example, the various stages of an insect's life would be referred to as *a life cycle*.

It eventually comes down to context and that is the responsiblity of the individual writer/author/editor, etc.

Comment: Can you give an example of the term used referring to a single concept?

Comment: @joedragons: I guess its use in product lifecylce management might be an example. (I am not a native speaker).