# submatrix or sub-matrix?

Tags: mathematics

I 've seen several times "submatrix" in code and manuals. However, whenever I write in my Latex editor, it gets underlined in red, as a spelling mistake. Same things happens now, just as I am writing my first question here. On the other hand, 've gets the same treatment, but that should be just a failure in the spelling checker (because it's not a word).

So, submatrix or sub-matrix? Or none of them, but something else?

---

*EDIT*

A related question lies [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/should-i-use-hyphens-with-prefixes-like-sub-and-semi?rq=1), but it's content is general, so does the duplicate of that question too. Moreover, as explicitly stated there, it depends on the word.

Comment: @FumbleFingers not really. You commented when I was editing.

Comment: I was just about to edit my closevote comment to make the same point! :) For what it's worth, Google Books has twice as many written instances of [submatrix](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22submatrix%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as it does of [sub-matrix](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sub-matrix%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but I'd have to say anyone who champions *either* as "correct" and the other "wrong" is anal beyond belief. (Present company excepted, @Alex W, since you just posted within my "comment edit window"! :)

Comment: No problem, there were pretty close. @FumbleFingers really valuable comment, thank you.

Comment: Haha thanks for the exception. I updated my answer to reflect that it is simply *a* correct spelling and not *the* correct spelling which is a good distinction to make.

Comment: The general case is covered in the 'duplicate'. Individual cases are possibly best tackled first of all by looking at corpus data. You could have presented the results given by others (though the Google NGram data is dated).

Comment: In some contexts one might prefer to use "sub-matrix" in a discussion of, say, data structure, to emphasize the "subness" of the entity.  But that's purely an "artistic" choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2008, *submatrix* was approximately [3 times more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sub-matrix%2Csubmatrix&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csub%20-%20matrix%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubmatrix%3B%2Cc0) than *sub-matrix*:

[image]

Although both spellings may be "generally [acceptable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68642/should-i-use-hyphens-with-prefixes-like-sub-and-semi)", *submatrix* is preferable by virtue of its "popularity". Neither expression is very common, but the relative popularity of *submatirix* is rooted in its adoption as the default spelling, particularly in the field of mathematics, so a person who used *sub-matrix* would reveal a basic ignorance of its predominant mathematical milieu.

Spellcheck dictionaries are not exhaustive, so *submatrix* is **marked as incorrect** simply because, as a rarely-used word, it is not included in the dictionary. Sub-matrix is "accepted spelling" because of [spellcheck hyphenation protocol](http://wordfaqs.mvps.org/masterspellcheck.htm#HowItWorks), which merely checks for correct spelling on either side of the hyphen.

Comment: This is in agreement with FumbleFingers's comment. However, the acceptable link you have there, is the question I linked to! Moreover, the link is for the general case, not that specific case! That's not good. However, I like very much your graph. If you update your answer, I might consider accepting it. +1 for the graph. If you do edit, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Bridget. Your edit adds value to your answer. Can you cite and link to a source that supports your spellcheck thesis?

Comment: The results are 15 years old, and the ratio seems more like 8 : 1 rather than 10 : 1 in 2000.

Comment: Your helpful observations informed a significant update, @EdwinAshworth. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. **Submatrix** is a correct way of typing it.  The spell checker is making a mistake.

> **Submatrix** *noun* 1. a set of certain rows and columns of a given matrix.

- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/submatrix)