# What is the correct spelling: "double-wide" or "double wide" or "doublewide" trailer?

Tags: orthography

I am referring to the style of home created when two single trailers are bolted together and lived in as a single unit.

Comment: You can find answers to such questions by simply looking in a dictionary. If you still can't find an answer, add a note stating what you looked up etc.

Answer (score 1):

Both [double-wide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double-wide) and [doublewide](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doublewide) are acceptable. However, it is, IMHO, better to stick to the hyphenated option.

"Double wide" is incorrect. The rules/guidelines of hyphenation are explained in [this excellent answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34766/23608).

Answer (score 0):

It can't be a *double wide trailer* because modifiers that come before nouns must be single words (see [John Lawler on the "eleven-year-old boy rule"](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/hyphen.html)).

Google Ngram Viewer suggests that *double-wide trailer* is the most common spelling, but *doublewide trailer* is also in use.

[image: Google Ngram Viewer for double - wide trailer,doublewide trailer]

Compound terms often start out hyphenated, but as people become familiar and start to treat the term as a unit, the hyphen disappears. For example, *ball-point pen*, initially the more common spelling, was overtaken by *ballpoint pen* around 1975:

[image: Google Ngram Viewer for ball - point pen,ballpoint pen]

Answer (score 0):

British English doesn't generally use *double* with an adjective in this way, it's normally a noun (or a past participle like *double-fronted*).

**Double-width** would be correct. Double is always† hyphenated when compounded like this, and **doublewidth* is wrong.

† Except in neologisms like *doublethink*.

Comment: "[The term "double-wide" is a set phrase, and anyone who referred to a "double-width trailer" would be indicating complete unfamiliarity with the topic.](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=800213)"

Comment: @GarethRees That's ***exactly*** why I prefaced my answer with "British English"; from your link: "A double wide is a very common phrase in American English though, apparently, not in UK English."