# Why does the writer use multiple hyphens?

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is a lengthy combination of words with hyphens like “the worst not-technically-in-a-recession year in American history” a new fashion of writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/is-a-lengthy-combination-of-words-with-hyphens-like-the-worst-not-technically-i)

> But I have found that people who don't have it are frequently the ones hell-bent on writing stories. I'm sure anyway that they are the ones who write the books and the magazine article on how-to-write-short-stories.
>
> (from *Mystery and Manners* by F. O'Connor)

In this passage, "how-to-write-short-stories" is preceded by "on" and doesn't modify a noun. Could anyone explain this  usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a device to force the phrase to be treated as one word. The implication is that the articles is about a specific thing, a particular way (or perhaps a set of rules) for writing stories.

They could have got a similar effect by using capital letters, implying that the phrase was a name:

> the magazine article on How To Write Short Stories.

In either case, the effect is rather dismissive: the writer is implying that the articles are about some magic formula that the writer does not value greatly.