# A What-Do-You-Call-It question

Tags: hyphenation

In a book, there is this sentence:

"My mom would have put this in her What-Have-You-Done-Now? File, but it was SOS to me."

-p 19, The SOS File, Betsy Byars.

Is there a name for this kind of hyphenated phrase-as-title? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Compound adjective hyphenation, or multiple word hyphenation?

Comment: [**Phrasal adjective**:](http://grammarist.com/grammar/phrasal-adjectives/) *When a phrasal adjective precedes a noun, it usually takes a hyphen or, **for phrases of three or more words, hyphens***.

Comment: +1 for the self-referential title. :) When I first saw the question, I was going to complain that the title was too generic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That should be made into an answer

Comment: @Jim: Except I don't know if there's such a thing as a phrasal adjective that *doesn't* precede a noun (because it comes *after* the noun?). Nor do I know the terminology for distinguishing the two types (if indeed there are two).

Comment: See also [Is a lengthy combination of words with hyphens like “the worst not-technically-in-a-recession year in American history” a new fashion of writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/84296/191178)

Answer (score 1):

The generic name is *[placeholder name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name)*.

However, in computer science, the term is *[metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable)*, and through the wide spread of modern "hacker" and computer cultures, *metasyntactic variable* has taken on the role of *placeholder name* in some corners of the Internet.