# Is there a way to noun a prepositional verb phrase?

Tags: grammar, phrases, verbs, nouns, productive-affixes

I'm not precisely sure how to ask this. I can turn certain verb phrases into nouns, and they sound good. The major reason to do this would be facetiousness but the grammatical aspect intrigues me. Some examples:

> I like to hit home runs. -> I like home-run-hitting.
>
> I often attack bears. -> I often go bear-attacking.

However, with prepositional verb phrases, it doesn't seem to work out.

> I enjoy standing on desks. -> I enjoy on-desk-standing*.
>
> He's good at taking care of things. -> He's good at of-things-taking-care*.
>
> He is known to rely upon God. -> He is known for his upon-God-relying.

Are the first two productions correct, and if so, what's the technical term for them? And, is there any way to get a correct result for the latter three productions and others like them?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'? Svartvik postulated a five-point gradience of 'acceptability', but I've never heard of it being passed into law by Parliament. Your first two are possibly 'dubious' (not quite as bad as the bottom category) or perhaps 'ill-established' (contrast accepted compounds like bear-hunting) while the last two are probably 'unacceptable'.  If you want to appear quirky, you will do.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Quirkiness is indeed part of the goal, but also aesthetic appeal. This is playing with the language: given the way it is set up, how can I (ab)use its grammatical rules to convey something in a (hopefully) delightful way. And to be delightful it has to conform to the "rules" where necessary. I am not sure how best to describe it but something clicks when I read "home-run-hitting" and my brain says: "this makes sense". Not so with "of-things-taking-care". Yet even that is better than some others: "caring-of-take-things" would be even more nonsensical.

Comment: That being said the answer may be that the "ing" examples on the left already are noun phrases: "'Taking care of things' is something I'm good at" - it functions as a noun in that sentence, right?

Comment: There's already an English noun, *caretaking*, for *taking care of*. So you could say *things-caretaking* (as opposed to *building-caretaking* or *child-caretaking*, which are the usual meanings).

Comment: Were it not for your broadening of the question to include premodifiers cobbled together from V + P (and perhaps MWV?) constructions, this would be a near-duplicate of [Is a lengthy combination of words with hyphens like “the worst not-technically-in-a-recession year in American history” a new fashion of writing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84296/is-a-lengthy-combination-of-words-with-hyphens-like-the-worst-not-technically-i/200472#200472), where there is already an answer.

Comment: @Claudiu We already have the availability of the inverted pseudo-cleft _Standing on desks is what I enjoy._ or the perhaps semantically more accurate _Standing on desks is one of the things I enjoy._

Answer (score 4):

> [**Nominalisation**](http://aeo.sllf.qmul.ac.uk/Files/Nominalization/Nom%20LOC.html) is a ***noun phrase*** generated from another word class, ***usually a verb***.

Here's the [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/nominalization) definition, which also specifically mentions that the process can be used to form *noun **phrases*** (as opposed to the simplest case, which simply involves using a verb as a noun - for example [*a big spend*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SxClVeCyK9Oq8wfv1JJw&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22a%20big%20spend%22)).

OP's examples also feature...

> [**inversion**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(linguistics)) *- any of several grammatical constructions where two expressions switch their canonical order of appearance*.

(i.e. the "normal" sequence for *his upon-God-relying* would be *his relying/reliance upon God*).

Answer (score 0):

Alas there is no general rule.  The following work

> at-home business
>  stay-at-home mom
> on-time performance
>   over-the-counter medication
>  in-your-face attitude
>   outside-the-box thinking
>  out-of-this-world desserts
>  on-deck
>   batter

but "upon-God relying" doesn't.  I suspect that the ones that work are usually the ones that save extra words and awkward phrasing.  But I haven't done the research to back that up.