# Hyphen usage. Mono-channel and multi-channel or monochannel and multichannel?

Tags: hyphenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

While writing a technical paper about fiber optics this question about hyphens came out.

Should this words be used with or without a hyphen?

> - Mono-channel or monochannel
> - Multi-channel or multichannel

On published technical papers both forms are found. I would like to know which one is correct.

Thanks you.

Comment: Seconding the above. That said, going off the top voted answer for said question I'd say that multichannel and monochannel are 'more' correct, but both could probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what Google is telling me:

- "mono-channel" returns ~500,000 results
- "monochannel" returns ~100,000 results
- "multi-channel" returns ~19,000,000 results
- "multichannel" returns ~13,000,000 results

I would say that to describe a configuration involving multiple channels, use *either* "multichannel" or "multi-channel". Do not use both in the same paper; you want to maintain consistency.

To describe a configuration involving a single channel, "mono-channel" is acceptable, but "monochannel" is almost certainly non-standard (even my browser underlines it as a spelling error).

Personally, I would use "single-channel" rather than "mono-channel", as *single* is sort of the complement to *multiple*. Using the prefix *mono-* implies that you also want to be using the term *stereo-*, which is more specific than *multi-*.

Comment: Google is notoriously unreliable when it comes to hyphens. COCA actually prefers *multichannel* (111) over *multi-channel* (21), and by a larger margin to boot. It also does not have a *single* cite for either *monochannel* or *mono-channel*. *Single-channel* gets 42 hits. And of course it's likely that the real answer to this question is: different departments will have different guidelines; look at what your peers do; ask your professor/reviewer/publisher.

Comment: American publishers strongly prefer skipping the hyphen with *multi*.  [See here](http://oreilly.com/oreilly/author/stylesheet.html).