# reestablish vs. re-establish

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

Which form of this word is more appropriate for general use?

I would expect someone to misread *reestablish* more often than *re-establish*, however it is more consistent in context with *renew*, *reconnect*, and *retry*.

Comment: Here is an entry for [re-establish](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/re-establish?q=re-establish), there is no correponding entry for reestablish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number of dictionaries (e.g., [1](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reestablish), [2](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/business-english/re-establish?q=reestablish), [3](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Reestablish)) have entries for *reestablish* making it acceptable for general use. While I personally find the spelling a little jarring, I'm fairly certain that this is simply due to the fact that I do not come across this variant very often. If not, I would also find *cooperation* to be similarly disconcerting.

*Cooperation* used to be (and sometimes still is) spelt as *co-operation* to ensure that readers did not misread it as *coop-eration*. [This Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=co-operation,cooperation&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) confirms that *cooperation* is now the preferred choice. Similar cases can be made for [*preeminent* / *pre-eminent* and *preexisting* / *pre-existing*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=preeminent,pre-eminent,preexisting,pre-existing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). What has made this shift in preference possible is that none of these words in its unhyphenated form can be confused for some other word. An ELU [answer on hyphenating compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34766/23608) covers this issue well.

Therefore and returning to the case of *re-establish* vs. *reestablish*, it comes down to a question of popular usage and somehow gauging if one spelling trumps the other. On ELU, we do this by comparing Google Ngrams. The [following Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reestablish,re-establish&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for *reestablish* vs. *re-establish* suggests that the hyphen is steadily becoming unnecessary.

[image]

Narrowing this down further to specific corpora:

- [American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reestablish%2Cre-establish%2Creestablished%2Cre-established&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=): *reestablish* is preferred
- [British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reestablish%2Cre-establish%2Creestablished%2Cre-established&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=): *re-establish* is preferred
- [English fiction](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reestablish,re-establish,reestablished,re-established&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=16&smoothing=3&share=): *reestablish* is preferred

Another benchmark that can be used to gauge usage is Google Trends which examines web searches (along with other criteria). The AmE [trend comparison for *reestablish* vs. *re-establish*](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=re-establish,%20reestablish,%20re-established,%20reestablished&geo=US&cmpt=q) (and *reestablished* vs. *re-established*) further confirms that the hyphen-less variants are the ones preferred.

[image]

Going by the above results, it is fine and possibly a good idea to use *reestablish* in AmE and stick to *re-establish* with BrE. The implication is that AmE readers are unlikely to be confused or otherwise put off by the spelling. When writing for a world audience, the safer and less confusing option would be *re-establish*.

Answer (score 1):

When the prefix ends with the same vowel as the word it’s prefixing begins with, it’s common to use a hyphen to separate them.

When these letters are vowels, in older typesetting traditions, particularly those free of the typewriter’s tyranny, one used a diaeresis on the second vowel to indicate that it was in hiatus.

- re-establish, reëstablish
- co-occurrence, coöccurrence