# If it's cost-efficient, would it be cost-efficiency?

Tags: hyphenation

Dictionary.com is showing cost-efficiency, but  New York Times shows "cost efficiency."

Sentence would be: ... our track record for timeliness and cost-efficiency.

I feel like it should have no hyphen.

Thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Related: [Hyphenating compound words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

When you are producing a compound word like the adjective *cost-efficient* in "cost-efficient process" it is necessary to show that those two words form a single adjective.

However, *cost efficiency* is not the same: here *efficiency* is the noun and *cost* the adjective (attributive noun). Neither is a compound and it doesn't form one either.

Note that if you are using *cost efficiency* as a compound itself ("founded on cost-efficiency principles"), then it needs a hyphen to show it's a compound.