# Full-time or full time, part-time or part time?

Tags: orthography

Having a debate here over how to form the description of employment.

A) Bob works **full time** on the project.

B) Bob works **full-time** on the project.

The same applies for part time/part-time.

Which is (more) correct?

Comment: You may find [this discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word) to be interesting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It might depend where your 'here' is:

**full-time**

**adj**:
for the entire time appropriate to an activity

a full-time job; a full-time student

**adv: full time:** on a full-time basis:

he works full time

Compare part-time;  full-timer  n
Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991 . . .2003

**full-time**

**adj.:** working or operating the customary number of hours in each day, week, or month. Compare part-time.

**adv. :** on a full-time basis. [1895–1900]

[Bob works full-time]

full′-tim′er, n. Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary . . .

[quotes tidied slightly & augmented but not significantly changed]

You have to check individual acceptable styles individually (so Lumberjack's reference, while interesting and accurate, may not help here) and be prepared for different 'rulings' from different authorities.

Incidentally, the above two dictionaries are consistent in their treatment of part-time / part time. AHD doesn't include the adverb polyseme.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not clear on your first sentence where you said it may depend on where 'here' is. Are you saying different countries vary? This wasn't clear (to me) from your dictionary references.  If it helps, it's for an Australian situation.

Comment: Collins shows largely UK-preferred variants and RHKWCD US-preferred (as does AHD). I'm sorry that I can't say whether the Aussie preference is for the open or hyphenated form of the adverb polyseme. However, I'd not label either of the variants 'wrong'. You may want to check articles on 'compound words' both here and on the wider internet - but accepted and preferred styles are not constant either across time or across geographical boundaries. You need a good up-to-date Aussie dictionary.

Comment: thanks I'll look into which dictionaries are most commonly accepted here.

Answer (score 3):

Usually people are more unsure over whether it's *full-time* or *fulltime*. The correct is hyphenated. As an adjective/adverb (in this case, of working), it is hyphenated. This is the way these words are used most often.

Comment: Wrong. _One_ accepted way to write the compound adverb is to use a hyphen.