# How to hyphenate "right mouse click"

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

What's the proper way to hyphenate the expression "right mouse click".

I'm writing documentation for some software I wrote.

"Please right mouse click on ...".

Comment: Style suggestion: drop the word "mouse."  "Please right click on ..."  It is assumed that if you are clicking you will use the mouse to do so.  Also, you may find [this discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word) on hyphenation interesting.

Comment: FWIW, right-click is much more common than right click.  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right-click%2C+right+click&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: I once read a story in a computer magazine about an irate user who wrote the word "click" on a monitor with a marker after a support person told her to right-click on sometime.

Comment: Yes: but you are writing documentation which people will read. There is no ambiguity between *right click* and *write click*.

Comment: That was supposed to be funny :-p

Comment: You should not use right-click, because it is wrong for left-handers. You should use index-click and ring-(finger-)click.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Sure there is, since I always use my index finger — on my left hand.

Comment: @tchrist I as a right handed person would not understand what you meant by that. Also, I tend to right-click with my middle not ring finger. The standard terms are _left-click_ and _right-click_, since the 10% of the population that is left handed is also associated with a higher creativity and imagination (some say intelligence) I am sure they'll be able to figure it out so why confuse us right-handed plebes needlessly?

Comment: Then let it be a learning experience for them. Sometimes you have to aim for the 10%: nothing great was ever achieved by aiming low.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard phrasing is *right-click* without the word *mouse*. Other click based phrases:

- Single click
- Double click
- Right-click
- Left-click
- Middle-click
- Ctrl-click

And so on. Whether to use a hyphen or not is somewhat personal preference and there isn't a strictly correct way to use it. If you are writing documentation or for a periodical I recommend asking your superior for the relevant style guide.

Comment: Doesn’t work for us left-handers.  Need index-click not right-click, etc.

Comment: @tchrist - With all those adjustments us southpaws need to make in a right-handed world, do you really have that much trouble with this one? Moreover, _index-click_ won't work if my mouse is configured in the traditional way, but I happen to be moving it with my left hand. In that case, it's still a right-click. I appreciate your point, though.