# Is it makeup or make-up or make up?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

If you take a makeup test, is it correct to call it a makeup, make up, or make-up test?

I know that makeup is also what some people put on their faces to look different. I think that make-up is what is used when you "make-up something" as in do something late. I think that "make up" is when you create something. So if you take a "makeup quiz" what is the correct one to use?

Is the following a correct sentence:

> You can make-up the makeup exam?

Comment: Since I missed the first cosmetics test, the teacher created a new one for me on the spot. It was a make up make-up makeup exam.

Comment: A similar question, with very useful answers, is [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word). Note that English readily, over the course of time, drops the hyphen in compounded words, with notable exceptions that seemingly can be defined by rules.

Comment: @JEL: Yes, IMHO this question is a duplicate of that one. But it cannot be closed as a duplicate because it has a bounty. (Why does a bounty protect a question from being closed?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said:

> You can make-up the makeup exam.

Unless it's a make-up exam about cosmetics, this wouldn't be what you're looking for, especially since "make-up" is a descriptor and "make up" is an action.

> You can make up the make-up exam.

Would be a consistent, sensible convention. As noted by @J.R. below, it's not necessarily *correct* since Harvard lists both. However, this is the convention that I would use.

[Make up] as the action and [make-up] as the descriptor.

Makeup as a compound word used to represent cosmetics.

Comment: That's one convention that could be used, but hardly a definitive answer. M-W gives specific mention of [_makeup exam_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/makeup), with the descriptor as a single word (no hyphen); so does [OOD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/makeup). Harvard omits the hyphen as well (at least on [this web page](http://static.fas.harvard.edu/registrar/ugrad_handbook/current/chapter2/final_exams.html)), but Harvard's [Extension School](http://static.fas.harvard.edu/registrar/ugrad_handbook/current/chapter2/final_exams.html) leaves it in.

Comment: @J.R. I'll change my answer to recommend it as a convention rather than stating correctness

Comment: @J.R.: Maybe you could write an answer? I see that this question has almost 10000 views and we could all benefit form a more detailed answer.

Comment: @J.R.: The bounty expires in one day....

Answer (score 3):

1. Make up (verb)

   - Make up you mind. (to settle)
   - Twenty kids make up the class. (to constitute)
2. Makeup (noun, or attributive adjective)

   - The makeup of the diverse sample is reflective of the population at risk for diseases.
   - He wore makeup. (cosmetics, sometimes "make-up")
   - We will take a makeup test. (something that makes up for)

Comment: Thanks. I came here wondering about *genetic makeup*, which this answer addresses. But it would be better with some sources to back it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to take a test over, you make up the test. 
The test you make up is a make-up test. 
Be sure to put on your makeup before making up the make-up test.
(When used as an adjective, make-up requires a hyphen.)

Comment: Hello, AnaP. Are you saying that M-W and Harvard are wrong when they use the solid compound as an attributive adjective?

Answer (score 0):

As stated previously, "make up" is a verb, "make-up" is an adjective, and "makeup" is a noun. Therefore, if an esthetics student missed an exam on cosmetics and then missed the alternative exam, it is possible that the student would have to make up a make-up makeup exam.

Comment: Is this answer different from the comment by Digital Chris on Oct 31, 2014?