# How can pre be used

Tags: prefixes

What are rules or style guidelines when adding "pre" to the beginning of words. I know that this called a prefix and that illustrates my point. How/when can pre be attached without a hyphen?

Example: Preconstruction, Pre-construction, or pre construction.

Comment: This is now essentially a duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/53711), so I'm not voting to reopen.

Comment: Similar question about the use of ["pre" with or without the hyphen](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/323661/49731).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pre-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pre-&allowed_in_frame=0) (etymology)

> - ***word-forming element meaning "before," from Old French pre- and Medieval Latin pre-, both from Latin prae (adverb and preposition) "before in time or place,"***,  Old English fore "before"), extended form of root *per- (1) "beyond" (see per).
> - The Latin word was active in forming verbs. Also see prae-. Sometimes in Middle English muddled with words in pro- or per-.

[Usage note](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pre-):

> - This prefix is usually prefixed to words without using a hyphen (for example, prefix, predate).
> - A hyphen is used in the following cases:
>
>   - Where excluding a hyphen would be likely to lead to a mispronunciation of the word because "pre" appears not to be a complete syllable (for example, "pre-yaw course", which could be read as "prey aw course" if unhyphenated).
>   - Always in British English before the letter e (for example, pre-existing)
>   - Often in British English before other vowels (for example, pre-operative);
>   - Always in all varieties of English before a character other than a letter (for example, pre-1960).

(Wiktionary)

Comment: As in many such cases, in AusE we have adopted some British and some American forms, so that the hyphen rule for "pre-" and "re-" is something of a mixed bag.  So "re-enter" and "re-elect" would nearly always be hyphenated, and "pre-existing" would probably also be, but "preempt" and "reorganise" usually not. There are similar vagaries with the spelling of "co-" words, such as cooperate or co-operate.

Answer (score 2):

"Pre" is overused and wholly unnecessary. For example, there is absolutely no need to say one is going to "pre-book" a ticket for an event or a table at a restaurant because to "book" already means to buy a ticket or place a reservation in advance of the intended time. To say to "pre-book" is like saying one is going to "book book" a ticket or a table reservation - it just sounds silly.

This also goes for "pre-order". "Order" already means to make an request and/or payment for goods in advance so there is absolutely no need and no sense in saying "pre-order" because "pre" adds zero extra meaning.

Comment: So you're essentially saying avoid tautology when using the 'pre' prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style, and as such, you should be guided by your manual of style.  I use the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which lists *pre-* as a prefix that's closed (unhyphenated) when combined with other words.  Exceptions are

- the word following is capitalized or starts with a numeral (pre-Enlightenment, pre-1939)
- two or more words follow (pre-Revolutionary War)
- for new coinages, when the last letter of the prefix and the first letter of the word following are the same (pre-ergotic).  When these words become familiar, they also become closed (preempt).

Answer (score 0):

An action (verb) doesn't require "pre":

| Term | Literal meaning | Why "pre" is not required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| To pre-heat (an oven) | to heat before heating | We heat the oven before baking (pre-bake) and not before heating (preheat). |
| To pre-drill (a hole) | to drill before drilling | This means drilling a pilot hole. |
| To pre-make (a sandwich) | to make before it was made | The sandwich was made before being delivered (pre-delivered) to the store. |
| To pre-board (an airplane) | to enter before entering | It is more accurate to say, "We are boarding Group 1 (the elderly and infants), then Group 2 (the first class passengers), ... ." |
| To pre-record (an event) | to record before it was recorded | Either an event is live, or audience is watching a recording of the event. |
| To have a pre-existing health condition | to have it before having it | When applying for health insurance, a person either has an existing condition or not. |

"Pre" usually adds nothing to explaining an action. Pre-paid (tickets), pre-ordered, pre-painted, pre-installed (software), pre-planned, pre-conditioned, pre-selected, ...—the list goes on *ad nauseam*.

Comment: It's not all that clear what rules you're saying exist.

Comment: What is the source for the rules you quote above? // "We heat the oven before baking (pre-bake)" is unclear. In "pre-bake", is "bake" a noun or a verb? If a noun, then pre-heating does indeed precede the bake, so the argument against using "pre-heat" is unclear. If a verb, then the argument misunderstands "pre-" when used to prefix a verb: the verb used means the preparatory action, not the action it precedes. Prestressed concrete is stressed (compressed) before it is used, not "stressed before it is stressed".

Answer (score -2):

The suffix *pre-* is usually used to mean 'before'. Its opposite number *post-* is used to mean 'after'.

Here's a sporting example

- Preseason (before the start of the season).
- Postseason (after the regular season).