# Other special hyphenation examples than eight-teen

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, morphology, doubled-consonants

According to [*The TeXbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hEYuAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22The+Texbook%22+Knuth&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=eight-teen) [Don Knuth, 1984], solution to Exercise 14.8, the word **eighteen** should be hyphenated **eight-teen**. It is, indeed, standard practice in pre-reform German to contract triple consonants and have them re-appear when the word is hyphenated (e.g., **Schiffahrt** → **Schiff-fahrt**) but this is the only such case I heard about in English. The [*Dictionary of the British English Spelling System*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22Dictionary+of+the+British+English+Spelling+System%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRxr_ej5_MAhUJ62MKHVrjAA8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) [Greg Brooks, 2015] has this at §4.4.7, Extensions (1):

> Given ... *sixth*, *seventh*, ...*sixteen*, *seventeen* ... and *sixty*, *seventy* ..., one might have expected *eightth*, ***eightteen***, *eightty*, but these are always reduced to *eighth*, ***eighteen***, *eighty*.”

Nevertheless, there is no mention of hyphenation.

My questions are:

1. Have you ever noticed hyphenation of **eighteen** as **eight-teen** in
   some document?
2. Do you know of any other words requiring similar
   treatment?

Comment: Related question, [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word). Eighteen is just one of the words with its own [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=eighteen).

Comment: *Eighteen* hasn't been spelled with two central *t*s since Middle English (prior to 1500). ODO has [eight|een](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eighteen), but it's probably best not hyphenated at all.

Comment: In most cases, "eighteen" is too short to be hyphenated.  It should only be done under duress.

Comment: @HotLicks... or under the influence of ardent spirits.

Comment: Knuth suggests, but doesn't categorically declare that *eighteen* should be hyphenated as *eight-teen*. Here is the full context, from an edition of the book that 'incorporates the final corrections made in 1996':

Comment: Exercise 14.8: *Before 1998, some German words changed their spelling when split between lines. For example, 'backen' became 'bak-ken' and 'Bettuch' sometimes became 'Bett-tuch'. How can you instruct TeX [the typesetting program that is the subject of this book] to produce such effects?* After presenting the solution, Knuth gives the following throwaway comment: ***The English word ‘eighteen’ might deserve similar treatment.** TeX’s hyphenation algorithm will not make such spelling changes automatically* (emphasis mine). And that is all Knuth has to say on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Google Books examples of 'eightteen'***

A [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20quality%20product%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22eightteen%22) turns up a boatload of instances where *eighteen* is spelled *eightteen*, but the majority of them appear to be straight-up variant spellings, with no line break involved. Still, in a considerable number of instances—probably too many to be merely coincidental— *eightteen* appears at a line break and is broken between the double *t*'s. Many of these are from the eighteenth and nineteenth centuries. For example, from R. Denson, [*A New Travellers Companion Through the Netherlands*](https://books.google.com/books?id=C_tWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA236&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw2PGvyJ7MAhVP82MKHbzPBGY41AIQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (1754):

> From *Delft* to the *Hague* a boat goes of **eight-teen** times every day in the morning from 7 'clock, till half hour past 7. at night almost every half hour the freight is 2. pence half penny.

From"An Officer," [*The Gentleman's Guide in His Tour Through France*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lTlYAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWu-Lhxp7MAhUU-GMKHXU6ArQ4jgIQ6AEITzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (1783):

> I must beg leave to observe, it is a general conceived notion in England, that is necessary to have a considerable fortune to make the tour of France: so it is, I confess, if a man is determined to be a dupe to Frenchmen, and enter into all the follies, vices, and fopperies, of that vain, superficial people; but I can with veracity declare, that during **eight-teen** months I was abroad, it did not cost me 150l. sterling.

From George Taylor, [*A History of the Rise, Progress, and Suppression of the Rebellion in the County of Wexford in the year 1798*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Pr5VAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA123&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCh4avvp7MAhUBE2MKHWZwCaw4PBDoAQg-MAY#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (1829):

> The third time they took out **eight-teen**, and were massacring them, when Dick Monk rode into town from Vinegar-hill, with 'his shoes and Stockings off, and shouting, “ D—n' your souls you vagabonds, why dont you go out and meet the enemy that are coming in, and not be murdering thus in cold blood?".

From Samuel Cooper, [*A Dictionary of Practical Surgery*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kxo4AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA385&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCh4avvp7MAhUBE2MKHWZwCaw4PBDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false), seventh edition (1838):

> Mr. Saunders found, that the greatest success attended the operation between the ages of **eight-teen** months and four years.

From "[The New John Gilpin](https://books.google.com/books?id=AmRIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8gaPlxJ7MAhVK32MKHfLzDhM4eBDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false)," in *Punch* (1846):

> Now RICHARD COBDEN said to him,/"Protected Corn has been/Thro' thrice ten tdious years, since **eight-**/**Teen** hundred and fifteen.

And more recently, from Farley Mowat, [*The Farfarers: A New History of North America*](https://books.google.com/books?id=O1FgRGgA_AoC&pg=PA214&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCh4avvp7MAhUBE2MKHWZwCaw4PBDoAQhDMAc#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (2011):

> Now I found myself on the verge of a depression whose size and shape were a good math for most of the boat-roofed house foundations scattered across the eastern Canadian Arctic. Roughly fifty feet long (nobody had a tape measure, so we had to pace it) it was perhaps **eight-teen** wide.

And from Gregory Miller, [*Daddy & Daddy Against the Odds*](https://books.google.com/books?id=elRx9DYueSMC&pg=PA43&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9ismIw57MAhUL32MKHSHoB0M4RhDoAQhBMAc#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (2012)

> They had a pool in the back yard and a patio covered with grapevines and a Botchy Court. Our bedroom was about **eight-teen** feet long by ten feet wide. The living room was just as big.

In contrast, we have this early example from Adam Smith, [*An Inquiry Into the Nature and Causes of the Wealth of Nations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SR9SAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA334&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw2PGvyJ7MAhVP82MKHbzPBGY41AIQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (1784):

> The rise in the price of porter, occasioned by an additional tax of three shillings upon the barrel of strong beer, has not raised the wages of common labour in London. These were about **eigh-teen**-pence and twenty-pence a day before the tax, and they are not more now.

---

***Assessment of the Google Books results***

In significantly more than half of the 70-odd Google Books matches for "eightteen" that I spot-checked, the word appeared as a chapter number or on a line of text where it was not severed by a line break. Evidently, in these instances, it was either a variant spelling or a typographical error. But especially between the 1700s and the very early 1900s, *eightteen* appeared often enough at line breaks to suggest that there may have been some intention in at least some cases to duplicate the *t* because of where the word fell on the line.

It is important to understand the relatively low frequency of these occurrences, which may be illustrated by an Ngram chart mapping *eightteen* (blue line) versus *eighteen* (red line) across the period 1700–2005:

[image]

Throughout the period, the incidence of *eightteen* is so low in comparison to the frequency of *eighteen* that the line for it looks completely flat. A look at the frequency of *eightteen* alone across the same period shows that the word's period of greatest frequency was between 1750 and 1900 (as the individual Google Books results indicate, too):

[image]

Looking at the individual instances of *eightteen* in the Google Books results, I was struck by how rarely the matches included a discussion of the spelling. The two exceptions from the period between 1900 and 2015 appear in Greg Brooks, [*Dictionary of the British English Spelling System*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sgh2CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=%22Dictionary+of+the+British+English+Spelling+System%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRxr_ej5_MAhUJ62MKHVrjAA8Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22eightteen%22&f=false) (2015), cited in the OP's question, and in Henry Shaw & Richard Dodge, [*The Shorter Handbook of College Composition*](https://books.google.com/books?id=gzNKAAAAYAAJ&q=%22eightteen%22&dq=%22eightteen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQxoa_ip_MAhUB22MKHTv5DNgQ6AEIPjAH) (1965) [combined snippets]:

> When two words [or a prefix and a word, or a word and a suffix] are combined, the first ending with the same letter with which the second begins, be sure that both letters are included.
>
> > accidentally irresponsible really bathhouse meanness roommate bookkeeping misspelling suddenness cruelly occasionally unnecessary dissatisfied overrated unnoticed drunkenness override withholding
>
> The only important exception to this rule is *eighteen*, which, of course, is not spelled ***eightteen***.

---

***Conclusion***

It thus appears that the recommended rule that the OP finds in Don Knuth, [*The TeXbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hEYuAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22The+Texbook%22+Knuth&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22eight-+teen%22) (1984) is not one supported in the past 100 years by any other book in the Google Books database. I might add that my electronic searches of that book for the words "eightteen," "eight-teen," and "eight- teen" all came up empty.

Whether some eighteenth- or nineteenth-century publishers consciously added a second *t* to *eighteenth* for aesthetic reasons when the word broke at a line break is unclear (though not impossible). But it seems unlikely that any such rule has held sway at any major English-language publisher in the past century.

Answer (score 1):

*The T<sub>E</sub>Xbook* is suggesting the addition of an extra *t* to *eight-*

*teen* only when hyphenating it for a break at the end of a line.

As useful as duplicating the *t* seems, I had never heard of it.
 [Bookshelf check: Although the 21st (1992) printing
 of the same book mentions *eight- teen,*
 the first printing only mentions two German words.]
Fascinating idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the related special case of avoiding triple consonants when adding a suffix, so it's *hull-less* oats and *wall-less* bacteria and classrooms.