# Is "family-owned-and-operated business" punctuated correctly?

Tags: punctuation

Is "family-owned-and-operated business" punctuated correctly? Yes or no?

Certainly looks better than:

a family-owned- and -operated business

And in predicative position, is this okay? "The business was family-owned-and-operated." Or drop the hyphens altogether in this construction?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not "punctuated" but "hyphenated". You should retag the question from "punctuation" to "hyphenation".

Comment: Your counter example is wrong, which is why it looks wrong. "Family-owned and -operated" would be the way to hyphenate it if you like dangling hyphens. It's what I'd do in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Both phrases use hyphens correctly to form a compound
“phrasal” adjective, *family-owned-and-operated*:

> ... family-owned-and-operated business ...
>
> The business was family-owned-and-operated.

Neither phrase needs hyphens, however, in an unambiguous context:

> Smith's Roadhouse was a family owned and operated business.
>
> The business was family owned and operated.

Many writers omit unnecessary hyphens for the sake of neatness.
In comparison, the hyphens should indeed be included here:

> The business was family owned and operated for years.

Was the business family-owned during all the years that it was in operation?

**Further reading**

[EL&U – When is it necessary to use a hyphen in
 writing a compound word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/34766/153448)

[Wikipedia –
 Compound modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_modifier)

[Get It Write – Compound Words:
 When to Hyphenate](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/042703CompWdsHyph.htm)