# Chatroom or chat room?

Tags: differences, nouns, spacing

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chat_room):

> The term chat room, or chatroom, is primarily used to describe any form of synchronous conferencing, occasionally even asynchronous conferencing.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chat%20room) lists **chat room** as the main term, with **chatroom** as a variant. [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/chatroom) does the opposite. None of these sources elaborates on the difference in usage, if any, between the two terms.

### **Is there any difference between a "chatroom" and a "chat room"?**

- Is one term more correct than the other?
- Should they be used in slightly different circumstances?
- Which one is older, and which one developed from it?

<sub>Question [inspired](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28573361#28573361) by @Slytherincess in a chatroom - or possibly a chat room.</sub>

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style, 14th Edition contains the following on the hyphenation or otherwise of compounds:

6.38: The trend in spelling compound words has been away from the use of hyphens; there seems to be a tendency to spell compounds solid . . .

Comment: @Close-voter: how is this "primarily opinion-based"? I'm always open to criticism, so please let me know if there's some way I can improve this question! :-)

Comment: You might have to restrict it to one *manual of style*, a small selection of them, or if-and-where a consensus lies. Otherwise it's POB depending on which dictionary you're reading. The CMS is in a way just more opinions but at least it's a published, vetted and respected work.

Comment: I suppose the question highlighted in bold at the time of this comment can be answered in a binary fashion (e.g. it's a matter of style, but *they are equivalent*). Which *style* is 'more correct' is then a matter of opinion. (I'm not the down-voter / close-voter.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-is-it-necessary-to-use-a-hyphen-in-writing-a-compound-word)

Comment: I've been waiting for someone to find the duplicate I remember. It doesn't address this particular example, but gives the general guidelines, which are not very rigid or predictable. Looking these things up is the only way to try to decide on which is most common, and even then it may not be clear. The question should be close-voted IMO, but it would take hours of debate deciding which reason/s applies/apply.

Comment: This doesn't seem "primarily opinion-based" to me.  If the answer is that both are in widespread use and there is no difference, then that's an answer, not a close reason.  Voted to reopen.

Comment: Stack that exists because of the belief that there's a standardized version of the language. Question put on hold because there's no standardized version of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Both are all right. Time ago we used to write some nouns + nouns separated and then with a hyphen in between, but currently we tend to write them together.

Comment: "All right? You mean alright, amirite? /ducks and runs