# "grey scale" or "greyscale"; one word or two?

Tags: orthography, compounds

Is the correct spelling "grey scale" or "greyscale"? I'm not sure whether or not to write it as a compound; it's in the context of a black-and-white video stream.

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is *grayscale*.

Comment: @WillSherwood- Depends on what side of the Atlantic you're on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OED entry for *greyscale* shows a familiar progression of [compound formation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889). The earliest entry, from 1857, refers to *grey scale*; from 1961, there is a citation about a *grey-scale* chart, and by 1994 there is a mention of *greyscales*.

A quick Ngram of variations of *greyscale image* (in order to exclude most scales which are grey, and [Martinian afflictions](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Greyscale)) shows all three forms in use, but the closed form being most common for both *gray* and *grey*.

[image: Google NGram showing 'grayscale image' to be more prevalent than 'gray-scale image' and 'gray scale image']