# Is "very first" hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

In the sentence:

> That was my very first phone.

should the words "very" and "first" be hyphenated?

I've read that "first" and "ever" should be hyphenated, but what about "very" and "first"?

Comment: Duplicate: [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces).

Answer (score 2):

'Very' and 'first' should not be hyphenated. 'Very' is an adverb and grades the adjective/number 'first'.

I have never heard that 'first' and 'ever' should be hyphenated. Not in British English anyway.

http://www.glossophilia.org/?p=5808

Comment: Why are we supposed to pay any attention to Louise Barder (of *glossophilia*)? Because she has dual citizenship or because she had a career in classical music?

Comment: I downvoted because, as deadrat says, the source seems to basically be one person's opinion, and I disagree with Barder's argument in the linked post that "first ever" is somehow improper because "first" is an "absolute adjective" that cannot be modified. I thin the argument is silly because there are obviously different kinds of firsts: you for example speak of "the first phone that I bought on my own", which might be different from "my first phone". The relative clause "that I bought on my own" modifies the meaning of "first" here, so it is evidently not impossible to modify it.

Comment: People saying that tautologies are always wrong don't seem to be aware of the pragmatic aspects of the language. 'Very' may judiciously be used as a pragmatic emphasiser, when one considers double-bolding or switching to a bright red typeface perhaps too in-the-face.

Answer (score 1):

Hyphenation is a matter of punctuation, and punctuation is a matter of style, so you should be guided by your manual of style. I prefer the *Chicago Manual of Style*, which does not list *first ever* as a compound noun and would thus not advise a hyphen in a sentence like

> It was the **first ever**.

Supposing that *ever* is interpreted as an adjectival abbreviation for *ever-seen*, the *CMS* would consider the term a compound of the class adverb not ending in *-ly* followed by an adjective, and the advice would be to hyphenate:

> It was the **first-ever** occasion.

The Ngram viewer find plenty of examples of both forms, so it's up to you (or your editor).

Comment: But what about "very first"?

Comment: @sumelic Great start for the new year. *CMS* would say the same for *very first*, adverb, not *-ly* + adjective.

Comment: I wondered if "very" might count as a special adverb that wouldn't be hyphenated even though it doesn't end in *-ly.* For some reason, "very-first" looks wrong to me.