# Compound wording and how to write it

Tags: compounds

Which one is right? "We show how formal models of

hardware peripherals improve the state-of-the-art security models."

or

"We show how formal models of

hardware peripherals improve the state of the art security-models."

Or something else?

I'm writing a paper about formal models of computer peripherals where the above term occurs.

Comment: See if this helps: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is correct.  "We show how formal models of

hardware peripherals improve the state-of-the-art security models."

Comment: An answer without justification is rarely considered a good answer. There re numerous style authorities that provide guidance on this subject. Could you provide a reference and an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is the correct one because the hyphen used in that binds the word and that can be considered as one single term tHat is used in reference to the security model.