# What is the difference between these two words?

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

Which one is correct:

> short answer question

or

> short-answer question

If both of them are correct how do they differ from each other?

Comment: There's no significant preference one way or the other for hyphenating [**high-strength concrete**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=high+strength+concrete%2Chigh-strength+concrete&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chigh%20strength%20concrete%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chigh%20-%20strength%20concrete%3B%2Cc0), for example. Use whichever you like best - it's more a matter of *style* than "grammatical rules", and obviously in both that and OP's cited context there's no possibility of different *meanings*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short-answer question would be more correct in any plausible situation.

Having the dash just directly correlates the fact that what you're looking for is a "short answer" to your question, without having to write it out as I have.

On a technical level, neither are incorrect but readability is greater in the latter option.