# Which spelling should I use: "grass roots" or "grassroots"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, compound-words

Both [Oxford Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grass_roots) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grass%20roots) dictionaries show *grass roots* with a space between the two words in the compound noun.

But this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grass+roots+are%2Cgrassroots+are%2Cgrass+roots+have%2Cgrassroots+have&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrass%20roots%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrassroots%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrass%20roots%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrassroots%20have%3B%2Cc0) shows substantially more hits for *grassroots* without a space separating the two nouns since the 1990s.

Which if either spelling is best to use today, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces)

Comment: Actually no, because "grass roots" is still the nominal form, which an n-gram is unable to distinguish from an adjectival form "grassroots."

Comment: @KarlG Have you seen my ngram? It compares "grass roots are"/ "grassroots are"/ "grass roots have"/ "grassroots have".

Comment: Ah, so it can distinguish. Sorry.

Comment: It would be reasonable to include further research in a question such as this. Other dictionaries (eg [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grassroots)) give both spellings. 'Which is the correct noun spelling?' is not well phrased. You can choose which to use at the present time; however, it looks like the closed compound is becoming the favoured choice [Ngram results], so it is probably sensible to join the descriptivist camp now.

Comment: What makes you think one of those is wrong?

Comment: @JK2 I don't know why it's missing from the one entry, but the US version of [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/grass_roots) lists both spellings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is certainly reasonable. I have noticed that dictionaries are somewhat slower than popular usage to pick up on spelling shifts that involve closing up hyphenated words or reducing two-word phrases to single words.

In the case of *grassroots* versus *grass roots*, *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) lists *grassroots* as the preferred form for the adjective (with *grassroot* as an alternative) and *grass roots* as the preferred form for the noun. But as recently as the *Ninth Collegiate* (1983), MW offered no adjective form of the term, suggesting that it considered the normal form of the adjective to be either *grass roots* or *grass-roots*. That changed in the *Tenth Collegiate* (1993), when *grassroots* debuted as the preferred adjective form.

*The Concise Oxford English Dictionary*, tenth edition, revised (2002), meanwhile, echoes the *Ninth Collegiate* in offering only *grass roots* as the spelling for the noun form and no spelling for the adjective form.

For its part, *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2010) lists *grassroots* as the only standard form for both the noun and the adjective. AHDEL came to this preference rather recently, however: in the fourth edition (2000), it listed *grass roots* as the noun form and *grass-roots* as the adjective form.

Clearly we are dealing with a term whose spelling is in flux—with Oxford holding to the traditional two-word or hyphenated spellings for the noun and adjective forms, Merriam-Webster opting for two words for the noun and one word (unhyphenated) for the adjective, and American Heritage endorsing the one-word form for both noun and adjective forms. My money, if I were a betting man, would be on the one-word form to triumph eventually, since the historical movement in spelling seems to favor it; but today we live in unsettled times, and the correct noun spelling of *grass roots*/*grassroots* depends on which authority you consult and how impressed you are by it.

---

**Update (January 12, 2021)**

To provide a bit of real-world context, I offer the following Ngram chart of word/phrase frequency for the terms "grass roots" (blue line) versus "grassroots" (red line) versus "grass root" (green line) versus "grass root" (yellow line) for the period 1900–2019:

[image]

This comparison is not subtle, in that it doesn't distinguish between "grass roots" as a noun, an adjective, or a subject and verb (for example). Nevertheless, it tracks a quite striking rise in frequency of "grassroots" from essentially zero prior to 1940 to a plurality of usage by 1980 to a dominant position over the past three decades.

On the strength of these results, it's easy to see why AHDEL, fifth edition (2010) has embraced *grassroots* as the standard spelling and why MW began treating *grassroots* as the preferred spelling of the adjective form of the term in 1993.

As Edwin Ashworth notes in a comment beneath this answer, it is a truism that—to the extent that it takes a descriptivist approach to orthography—a dictionary will necessarily be somewhat behind times on current real-world spelling preferences in instances where those preferences are changing rapidly. Still, it bears observing that many dictionaries seem to exhibit a degree of inertial resistance to change when it comes to presenting words that they have spelled a certain way in the past, even when the tide of popular usage has clearly changed; and this inertial force, at some point, becomes difficult to distinguish from evidence-denying prescriptivism. After 40 years of real-world dominance of the form *grassroots* over the form *grass roots*, I think, a dictionary's continued insistence that *grass roots* is the only (or even the primary) acceptable spelling of the term qualifies as almost purely prescriptive.

Comment: It may be splitting hairs of angels dancing on pinheads, but Oxford Dictionaries Online is calling this a plural (compound) noun, not an adjective like MW is. I'll need to wait till I get back from Christmas to check whether the real OED follows their custom of labelling such noun senses “attributive” in use. I honestly can’t quite convince myself one way or the other whether regular “is-it-an-adjective?” syntactic tests work here, like for instance deciding how acceptable in meaning and form something like *“This movement is even more grassroots than that one is”* strikes me.

Comment: @tchrist: Your cautionary note is well taken. I imagine that Merriam-Webster was thinking of a simple situation such as "grassroots [or _grassroot_] movement" when it made its move to one word for the adjective form. But the fact that adjectiveness and nounness tend to merge in settings such as the one you suggest is likely to add impetus to the movement toward rendering _grassroots_ as a single word in all its parts-of-speech incarnations. The OED is unlikely to withstand that momentum much longer, I think.

Comment: '[D]ictionaries are somewhat slower than popular usage to pick up on spelling shifts' is a truism. They can't pick up on them before they qualify according to their usage tests, which reflect popular usage. 'There's a considerable time lag ...'? (Had to look that up.)