# biocompliant or bio-compliant

Tags: meaning

My high school chemistry textbook contained the following passage (the emphasis is mine):-

> The correlation between the structure and properties helps in
>   discovering new materials such as high temperature superconductors,
>   **biocompliant** polymers for packaging, ...

I wanted to know what biocomplaint meant. So I googled it and Google displayed a 'did you mean bio-complaint' suggestion. Is there any difference between the biocompliant or bio-compliant?

Comment: The general issue is addressed at [When should compound words be written as one word with hyphens ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *biocompliant* or *bio-compliant* is so new it hasn't even made it yet to dictionary.com.

When a new word is coined from elements previously known, it often contains a hyphen to signal the novelty. The prefix *bio-*, however, appears in so many new words without the hyphen, like *biodegradable*, that the hyphen is likely to disappear quickly as the word moves toward a more general usage. That means that both spellings will occur for a number of years. [Here](https://books.google.de/books?id=haRxDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT43&lpg=PT43&dq=%22bio-degradable%22&source=bl&ots=JO2rn-P1nY&sig=XC1vufingpfoTlokowhLE6Feriw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjl79TVjdXYAhUBriwKHRoQA2wQ6AEwFnoECAoQAQ), for instance, is a book from 2000 that uses *bio-degradable* in the title.

The hyphen carries no lexical meaning; the two words are identical.

Comment: 'Bio compliant', the open compound, is also to be seen on the internet, but will probably soon disappear from current use.