# Hyphenation question: two-week or two week follow-up?

Tags: hyphenation

Which one is correct?

- two-week follow-up
- two week follow-up

Comment: The Ngram for follow up/follow-up considerably favours the hyphenated version https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=follow+up%2C+follow-up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfollow%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfollow%20-%20up%3B%2Cc0. The Ngram for two week/two-week considerably favours the hyphenated version.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=two+week%2C+two-week&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctwo%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctwo%20-%20week%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd use the first one, as long as "follow-up" is a noun and not an adjective for a noun not listed.

Comment: Hello, Cliff. Answers unaccompanied by reasonable research on ELU may be close-voted even if otherwise correct. But this sort of question has been covered here before.

Answer (score -2):

There's not a need to hyphenate, and both examples are wrong, and so the correct answer would be,
two weeks follow up.

Edit: Sitting in a mixed clinic the doctor told the busy medical secretary 'two-week follow-up' and who mistook the job to take on a later date, and overhearing the phlebotomist wanted to take another blood sample, the nurse rushes the defibilator. The doctor looked at me some gray bp rising and grin exclaimed loudly for all to hear 'two weeks follow up' and even wrote it down that way on a pad and rushed off.

Yes contemplating the first one is absolutely correct, and thanks.