# Is there a technique used when someone splits a compound noun into two parts?

Tags: nouns, literary-techniques, compound-adjectives

My student has asked whether the splitting of the compound word keyhole into key hole is a particular literary technique. I didn't know! 
It's relevant to the text, as it is about disconnection and distance in relationships.

Comment: Check this [answer.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-com-pound-words-be-writ-ten-as-one-word-with-hy-phens-or-with-spac)

Comment: But "keyhole" is a single word (a compound noun) with the meaning a hole for a key. It's not a syntactic construction with "hole" as head and "key" as modifier, which could be construed to have a different meaning, i.e. a strategically important hole.

Comment: I would not have any problem with the split.  Despite BillJ's objection, no one would think that "asshole" and "ass hole" were different things.

Comment: Most compound words *originated* as two separate words placed beside each other, and they still have meaning if treated separately. Instead of saying *a keyhole*, you can say *a hole for a key* and it will be perfectly understandable. Or you could *just* put the space back in, also without a problem. Doing so might appear a little strange, but if it's in the right context, it might emphasize something you're trying to say. And, again, there's nothing *wrong* with splitting the words back into two again—especially if each word, on its own, *is* a valid word.

Comment: @JasonBassford - And it should be noted that, in quoted speech, adding or removing the space implies a difference in how the words are spoken.  With "key hole" more emphasis would be placed on "key", and the words would be more distinctly separated.