# Cellphone or cell phone?

Tags: word-usage

I want to get this right, so I’ve decided to get the opinion of all you smart folks out there.  I’ve seen the word written both ways, I personally write cellphone as one word, but I’ve seen it written as two words too.  Technically I would imagine that I can’t go wrong if I write cell phone, but I would feel better if I heard other opinions on the subject.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Ultimately, this is just a matter of convention; see *[When should com­pound words be writ­ten as one word, with hy­phens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889)* If there is no convention, pick one, or [pick a style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) to pick one for you.

Comment: There are a couple of votes to close as a duplicate of [When should com­pound words be writ­ten as one word, with hy­phens, or with spaces](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889), but the answers to that question offer no assistance on whether to choose a closed or open compound, so I think closing this current question as a duplicate makes little sense. Perhaps someone might like to provide a properly-researched answer on closed vs open, either on this question or at the linked one?

Comment: The [Associated Press recommends "cellphone"](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2011/03/associated-press-newstyles-email-and-cellphone.html#:~:text=The%20AP%20announced%20today%20that,site%E2%80%9D%20to%20%E2%80%9Cwebsite.%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score -2):

The most contemporary expression might be just *cell*.

If you have to go through the trouble of spelling it out, it should be *cell phone*. But 9 times out of 10, you should not go through that trouble.

> Call my cell.
>
> **Name**: **Age**: **Cell**:
>
> Please refrain from using cell phones or cellular devices during the performance.

Comment: You don't explain *why* it "should be" *cell phone* and not *cellphone*. You can find *cellphone* in several dictionaries, as well as examples of its use in major newspapers and the Associated Press, which suggests the closed form has its adherents.

Comment: Carly, you need to provide supporting evidence for these sweeping statements, and indicate which region or country you think they apply to. In my country almost no one uses the expressions *cell*, *cell phone* (however spelt) or *cellular device* when referring to a **mobile phone**. :-)

Comment: hello sir and is it not also further shortened to simply Mobile **=)** modern (1900-2020) N.Am.E . not neo modern. although this graph search parameters should be further refined, but just in volume the difference is several magnitude https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cell+phone%2Ccell%2C+cellphone&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccell%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccellphone%3B%2Cc0

Comment: This answer so bad, even Community♦ could not save it.