# Hyphens in compound words where the second word is a verb

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns, hyphenation, compounds

Do you hyphenate a compound word made from a noun and a verb, such as 'hand knitted', when the compound does not come before a noun? E.g.: 'This jumper is hand knitted.'

Comment: Yes, compounds are written as single words, sometimes hyphenated, as in the compound adjective "hand-knitted", which has a noun as first component and the past participle "knitted" as head. It corresponds to the syntactic passive "knitted by someone". Other similar compounds include "drug-related" (related to drugs), "home-made" (made at home) "safety-tested" (tested for safety).

Comment: @BillJ - if you can provide references, propose your comment as an answer - it's generally considered inappropriate on the StackExchange network to answer questions in the comments.

Comment: Also see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spac

Comment: **A hand-knitted jumper** versus **This jumper is hand knitted**.  Most style guides only used a hyphen when these things are prepositioned.

Comment: It makes no difference whether the compound adjective is attributive or predicative. It's still a compound that should be written as one word, in this case hyphenated.