# When using compound nouns, is the quantity of the first noun always ambiguous?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

My understanding is that *solution discussion* is grammatically correct, whereas *solutions discussion* is not.

However, when looking at *solution discussion*, I cannot say if it is a discussion about one solution, or multiple solutions.

When using compound nouns, is it always ambiguous?

Comment: It may well mean multiple solutions, depending on context. Incidentally. "solution discussion" is not a compound noun but a syntactic construction consisting of modifier+head.

Comment: _Why_ do you think that one is 'grammatically correct' and the other not? [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solution+discussion%2C+solutions+discussion&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) appears to show that _solution discussion_ is more common; however, all the examples found show the two words just happening to occur next to one another, not as part of a phrase. _Solutions discussion_ does occur as a phrase.

Comment: @BillJ I see. As a speaker of a Romance language, _solution discussion_ sounds weird to me, and I also don't like the ambiguity, but it's easier than saying discussion of solutions.

Comment: @KateBunting so that's interesting. I've heard many times that, as a general rule, adjectives and attributive nouns, in English, should be singular, with some exceptions, such as _sports news_. So, is it okay to break this rule and say _Solutions Discussion_ to do away with ambiguity (assuming the rule actually exists) ?

Comment: Whether or not a randomly constructed two-orthographic-word string N₁ + N₂ is an open compound noun (eg _particle board_), a strong collocation, a weak collocation, or a free combination is not predictable (certainly as far as non-native-speakers are concerned). It could even be classed as unacceptable on grounds of common sense (_hygiene supernova_). 'Discussion on solution' sounds far more idiomatic (natural) than 'solution discussion' or 'solutions discussion'. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive/610009#610009) for a related issue.

Comment: Cerberus answers the question about singular-form vs plural-form attributive noun usages at  [When are attributive nouns plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/when-are-attributive-nouns-plural); see also [Is there a rule for forming 'plural compound nouns'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474438/is-there-a-rule-for-forming-plural-compound-nouns/474505#474505).  Idiomaticity of either requires checking individual examples.

Comment: All these comments combined with the provided links, together, have helped me understand the various uses of attributive nouns. Thank you so much!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth An 'open compound' is a contradiction in terms. By its very definition, a compound is a single word consisting, not of two lexemes, but of two bases. Items like "particle board" are nominals consisting of modifier+base

Comment: @BillJ I've not found this in my copy, but [here LPH includes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/598040/why-are-compound-words-not-entirely-consistent): (CoGEL III 4, Quirk et al., 1985) 'AmE inclines to fewer hyphens than BrE, preferring words to be written either open ...  or SOLID (without separation) rather than hyphenated.' Please specify which school you cite rather than assume it's gospel. CGEL attribute correctly.